# What is better for sparkplugs, inconel super alloy or iridium?

Tags: vw, sparkplugs, turbocharger

I am buying new sparkplugs for my 2006 Volkswagen Passat 2.0T and i purchased pulstar be1h10 sparkplugs with a plasma core, but i am now being told that they are not good for my car because they arent iridium but they are made of an inconel super alloy. I did a bit of research and a majority of what i found is that inconel is actually a very strong and durable precious metal. I am wanting to know if i should use the pulstar spark plugs or if i should return them and buy iridium spark plugs. My other research also shows that pulstar spark plugs are actually really high quality. So what im wanting to know is if i should use the pulstar spark plugs or buy iridium sparkplugs. Would anything happen to my car if i do not use iridium sparkplugs?

Comment: Good job identifying some *properties* (strong, durable) that may be relevant.  It doesn't matter what *material* the sparkplugs are made from. You could use a sparkplug made out of chocolate if it performs well in your *specific* engine.  A material may be *generally* better, but that generality doesn't matter for your *specific* engine. There is probably a sparkplug that performs "best" in your *specific* engine.

Comment: I put "best" in quotes because mechanics and parts guys will tell you which one is "best", but "best" in this context means: **good enough to not cause problems.**  There may be more than one brand that meets that criteria.  Just stay away from the brand people *have had* problems with.

Answer (score 4):

There are two significant design differences between these plugs.

One: The Pulstar plug has a much wider center electrode than a typical iridium plug. A thinner electrode allows better spark plasma to fuel mixture exposure. This results in faster ignition and less misfire.

Second is metalurgy; Iridium melts at over 4000 deg F while Inconel melts at around 2500 deg F. The higher melting point of Iridium allows the finer wire electrode which in turn results in the benefits to ignition noted above.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using dg1h10 pulstar plasmacore over two years now on my Infiniti FX35 with 206000 mile on it and don't have any problems,I've experienced more power on my engine and best gas consumption, for what I experienced I surely recommend these plugs

Answer (score 0):

Inconel , AKA nichrome and a few other very similar alloys, are what plugs have always been made of  ( at least since the 50's). I have removed 16  manufacturers original platinum plugs with 100,000 miles . All looked perfect , I hated to throw them away . New replacement platinum plugs made no difference in performance or mileage.  I don't know why one would need better than 100,000 miles of excellent performance.